# how can I call an unnamed instance in javascript?

Tags: javascript, class, object, instance

So if I make a class, and then create new instances of that class without naming them -maybe with a loop that creates a bunch of instances- how can I call a specific (or unspecific) instance?  For example, if I'm generating a bunch a squares, but I want to move a specific one somewhere, how would I do that?

Sorry if this is a total noob question, or if I miss-used some terminology, but I'm pretty new to programming.

Example code:

```
function example(x){
    this.x = x;
}

for(var i=0; i<10; i++){
    new example(1);
}
//now how would I get a specific instance of examples to have x = say, 10.
```

Comment: Can you provide sample code for what you consider to be creating an instance without naming them?

Comment: Put them in an Array?

Comment: By the way, Javascript doesn't really have any such thing as a Class. It uses prototypal inheritance. An instance of an object is extended to form another instance of another type.

Comment: But how exactly would I do that Thesystem?  Would I push each instance of example into an array, and then call a certain part of that array to target a specific instance?  I think I understand, but could I please get some example code?

Comment: @Kyth'Py1k: To be honest, if you're not familiar with Arrays, it would seem that you should read through some introductory material. That's a pretty fundamental feature of the language.

Comment: Well, I;m familiar with arrays, I just wasn't exactly what you meant.  I now understand it from Louisbros's example.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get all instances of class in jquery or js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19526456/get-all-instances-of-class-in-jquery-or-js)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could put each square in an array and access them that way:

```
function Square(i){
    this.index = i;
}
Square.prototype = {
    constructor: Square,
    intro: function(){
        console.log("I'm square number "+this.index);   
    }
}

var squares = [];

for(var i = 0;i < 10;i++){
    squares.push(new Square(i));
}

squares.forEach(function(square){
    // do something with each square
    square.intro();
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/louisbros/MpcrT/1/