# Get all instances of class in Javascript

Tags: javascript, class, object

I thought there would already be an answer for this but I can't seem to find one..
How can I run a particular class method on all instances of this class in Javascript?

This has to be done in a situation where I do not know the names of the instances.
I think I could use some sort of static variable inside my class to store all instances, but this doesn't seem to exist in JS

So how to call my method on all existing instances of my class?
Note : just for clarification : I'm not speaking about CSS classes, I'm speaking about objects.

Edit : By Class in Javascript, I mean the creation of a new object on a function:

```
function something()
{
}

var instance = new something();
```

Comment: You're asking to create a memory leak.

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName()`? The jQuery [class selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/)? Am I missing something here?

Comment: @SLaks why? I don't get it.

Comment: @Juhana: See his last paragraph.

Comment: Ah, I see. (There are no classes in JavaScript, so the terminology threw me off.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Looping through all instances of a javascript object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247956/looping-through-all-instances-of-a-javascript-object)

Comment: Generally one only needs to know about a (hint!) *collection* of said objects. Use this idea to group objects into appropriate (hierarchical) collections and design the API around as such. For instance, a Map might have many Points, but one generally doesn't care about *every* Point that was created; rather, only the Points that belong to - by being in the appropriate points *collection* of - a particular Map are of interest.

Comment: What constitue a class for you in JS? Js is not class based but proto typed

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can create a static array and store it on your constructor function:

```
MyClass.allInstances = [];
MyClass.allInstances.push(this);
```

However, you need some way to figure out when to remove instances from this array, or you'll leak memory.

Comment: Ok, now I get why you're speaking about memory leaks. well I'll implement some sort of destructor

Comment: You can not put 'MyClass.allInstances = []' in the constructor, it will create empty array every time :(

Comment: @DamjanPavlica: Of course; those need to be in different places.

Comment: @DamianPavlica what about this `if(!MyClass.allInstances) { MyClass.allInstances = []; }`  ?

Answer (score 14):

In Chrome 62+ you can use [`queryObjects` from the console API](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/utilities#queryObjects) - which will **not work** in native JavaScript code but in the console so it's **great for debugging**.

```
class TestClass {};
const x = new TestClass();
const y = new TestClass();
const z = new TestClass();
queryObjects(TestClass)
```

Answer (score 11):

You'll have to provide a custom implementation.

I would do something like this :

```
function Class() {
    Class.instances.push(this);
};
Class.prototype.destroy = function () {
    var i = 0;
    while (Class.instances[i] !== this) { i++; }
    Class.instances.splice(i, 1);
};
Class.instances = [];

var c = new Class();
Class.instances.length; // 1
c.destroy();
Class.instances.length; // 0
```

Or like this :

```
function Class() {};
Class.instances = [];
Class.create = function () {
    var inst = new this();
    this.instances.push(inst);
    return inst;
};
Class.destroy = function (inst) {
    var i = 0;
    while (Class.instances[i] !== inst) { i++; }
    Class.instances.splice(i, 1);
};

var c = Class.create();
Class.instances.length; // 1
Class.destroy(c);
Class.instances.length; // 0
```

Then you could loop through all instances like so :

```
Class.each = function (fn) {
    var i = 0, 
        l = this.instances.length;
    for (; i < l; i++) {
        if (fn(this.instances[i], i) === false) { break; }
    }
};

Class.each(function (instance, i) {
    // do something with this instance
    // return false to break the loop
});
```

Answer (score 8):

Sorry for such a late reply, but I found myself trying to achieve this and I think this may be a simpler answer.

Say you want all instances of class MyClass, only get instances created at top window level (not including instances created inside a closure):

```
for (var member in window)
{
    if (window[member] instanceof MyClass)
        console.info(member + " is instance of MyClass");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Keyword 'static' could be used in classes now (but check support), ...

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static

```js
class Point{
    constructor(x, y){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        Point.all.push(this);
    }
    destroy(){
        let i = Point.all.indexOf(this);
        Point.all.splice(i, 1);
    }
    static all = [];
}

var p1 = new Point(1, 2);
var p2 = new Point(54, 33);
var p3 = new Point(297, 994);

console.log(JSON.stringify(Point.all)); //[{"x":1,"y":2},{"x":54,"y":33},{"x":297,"y":994}]

p2.destroy();
console.log(JSON.stringify(Point.all)); //[{"x":1,"y":2},{"x":297,"y":994}]
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to store a list of instances yourself:

```
function someClass(param) {

  // add to all
  if (this.constructor.all === undefined) {
    this.constructor.all = [this];
  } else {
    this.constructor.all.push(this);
  }

  // set param
  this.logParam = function() { console.log(param); };
}

var instance1 = new someClass(1);
var instance2 = new someClass(2);

for (var i = 0; i < someClass.all.length; i++) {
  someClass.all[i].logParam();
}
```

If memory leaks are a concern then you can create a method for deleting instances when you are done with them:

```
function someClass(param) {

  ...

  this.destroy = function() {
    var all = this.constructor.all;
    if (all.indexOf(this) !== -1) {
      all.splice(all.indexOf(this), 1);
    }
    delete this;
  }
}
```