# Javascript array, building from a set of variables

Tags: javascript, arrays

The variables following are defined through a `Car` prototype:

```js
var Car = function(maker, type, model) {
  this.maker = maker;
  this.type = type;
  this.model = model;
}

var golf = new Car('VW', 'Hatchback', 'Golf');
var sentra = new Car('Nissan', 'Sedan', 'Sentra');
var _328i = new Car('BMW', 'Convertible', "328i");
var gallardo = new Car('Lamborghini', 'Convertible', "Gallardo");
var corniche = new Car('Rolls Royce', 'Sedan', "Corniche");

Car.prototype.year = 0;

golf.year = 2015;
sentra.year = 2010;
_328i.year = 2019;
gallardo.year = 2020;
corniche.year = 1998;
```

How does one build an array of the var values for the property `maker`

Something that might console log like this:

(5) ['VW', 'Nissan', 'BMW', 'Lamborghini', 'Roll Royce']

Answer (score 1):

You could create an array of the car instances and use the [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function

```js
console.log(
  [golf, sentra, _328i, gallardo, corniche].map((car) => car.maker)
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As another commentator said, "There are a lot of solutions to that." Yours is interesting. I was thinking one could find the variables; golf, sentra etc. referencing the Car prototype and then the property 'maker'. You seem to manually entered the var names. If there were a hundred this might be burdensome. Any thoughts? Thanks

Comment: Raphael had my thought in mind. // Solution here
const makersList = Array.from([golf, sentra, _328i, gallardo, corniche], car => car.maker );

// should print an array of makers string names
console.log(makersList);

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of solutions to that. First, you need to make an array with all your cars, and then use a method to iterate on each car to get the car maker.

Here two examples:

```js
var Car = function (maker, type, model) {
  this.maker = maker;
  this.type = type;
  this.model = model;
}

Car.prototype.year = 0;

var golf = new Car ('VW', 'Hatchback', 'Golf');
var sentra = new Car ('Nissan', 'Sedan', 'Sentra');
var _328i = new Car ('BMW', 'Convertible', "328i");
var gallardo = new Car ('Lamborghini', 'Convertible', "Gallardo", 2020);
var corniche = new Car('Rolls Royce', 'Sedan', "Corniche");

golf.year = 2015;
sentra.year = 2010;
_328i.year = 2019;
gallardo.year = 2020;
corniche.year = 1998;

var cars = [golf, sentra, _328i, gallardo, corniche]
var carsMakers = []

for(var i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
  var c = cars[i]
  carsMakers.push(c.maker)
}
console.log(carsMakers)

var carsMakers2 = cars.map(function(c) { return c.maker });
console.log(carsMakers2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just like the `map` approach but using `Array.prototype.from`:

```js
var Car = function (maker, type, model) {
this.maker = maker;
this.type = type;
this.model = model;
}
var golf = new Car ('VW', 'Hatchback', 'Golf');
var sentra = new Car ('Nissan', 'Sedan', 'Sentra');
var _328i = new Car ('BMW', 'Convertible', "328i");
var gallardo = new Car ('Lamborghini', 'Convertible', "Gallardo");
var corniche = new Car('Rolls Royce', 'Sedan', "Corniche");

Car.prototype.year = 0;

golf.year = 2015;
sentra.year = 2010;
_328i.year = 2019;
gallardo.year = 2020;
corniche.year = 1998;

// Solution here
const makersList = Array.from([golf, sentra, _328i, gallardo, corniche], car => car.maker );

// should print an array of makers string names
console.log(makersList);
```

Comment: How is creating an array and using `Array.from()` and it's map function more performant than directly using the map function on the array? `Array.from()` is redundant here

Comment: Just one more way of doing the same thing. Will fix the performance allegation. If its redundant or not its up to the person asking :)

Comment: Thanks Raphael. Exactly.

Comment: Exactly, er, or maybe not. I thought you pulled the var names but in fact you entered them (?). Can you not pull the var names through the Car prototype reference (terminology might be wrong). Thanks

Comment: Then this is actually what you're looking for: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19526456/get-all-instances-of-class-in-javascript

Comment: But careful with using that approach in a professional context :)