# Display course and module in JS

Tags: javascript

The student wants to participate in a Course that has different modules

The module describes the cost of the course, the duration and the title

example:

```
let m1 = new Module ("React", 2, 45000);
```

that is, React will be studied for `2 months` and `45000 / monthly`

Course contains the course titles modules

for example:

```
let c = new Course ("React Pro");

c.addModule (new Module ("React", 2, 45000))

c.addModule (new Module ("Redux", 1, 50000));

c.Print ();
```

If the method is called, the name of the course in `h1` will appear on the screen, then the name of each module with the `<ul> <li>.`

At the end, print the whole value of the course in red

I have a question. What is `.addModule (new Module ("Redux", 1, 50000));`
Also, the loop `for... in` is not working.

What I have done so far:

```js
class Course{
    constructor(a,b){
        this.courseName = a;
        this.courseModule = b;
    }
    print(){
        let h1 = document.createElement("h1")
        h1.innerHTML = this.courseName
        document.body.append(h1)

    }
}

class Module{
    constructor(a,b,c){
        this.name = a;
        this.duration = b;
        this.price = c;
    }
    addModule(){
        for (let el in Module) {
            let ul = document.createElement("ul")
            let li = document.createAttribute("li")
            ul.innerHTML = el[this.name]
            document.body.append(ul)
        }

    }
}
let c = new Course("React Pro")
let m1 = new Module("React" , 2 , 45000)
let m2 = new Module("Redux" , 1 , 50000)
c.print()
m1.addModule()
m2.addModule()
console.log(m2)
console.log(m1)
```

Comment: Are you trying to loop over every instance of `Module`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get all instances of class in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19526456/get-all-instances-of-class-in-javascript)