# How to create an array of similar object effectively?

Tags: javascript, arrays, class, filter

I have an array of similar objects like this:

```js
const urls = [
    {
        title: "title 1",
        url: "https://example.com/1" 
    },
    {
        title: "title 2",
        url: "https://example.com/2" 
    },
    ...
]
```

To reduce the repetition, I think of making a class:

```js
class URL {
    title: string
    url: string
   
    constructor(title:string, url:string) {
        this.title = title
        this.url = url
    } 
} 

const link1 = new URL("title 1", "https://example.com/1")
const link2 = new URL("title 2", "https://example.com/2")
```

This has 2 cons:

- I have to assign unused variable names
- Create an array of them seem to lead to [memory leak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19526456/get-all-instances-of-class-in-javascript#comment28969112_19526456)

Is there a better way? My goal is to run a filter on the array (input a specific `title`, output its corresponding `url`).

Comment: Regarding the "unused variable names", you can push your instances directly to an array or create them within your array `const links = [new URL("title 1", "https://example.com/1"), ...]` etc. Creating an array of instances doesn't cause the memory leak (what does is when an instance can't be freed by garbage collection as it's being referenced somewhere else when you really no longer need that instance anymore).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you describe what you actually want is just a lookup using a title to obtain a URL.

You should not be using arrays for this at all (at least for a larger amount of URLs). Best to use a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) or a JS object since those are designed for lookups and can therefore do them very fast i. e. sub-linear.

From the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map#description):

> The specification requires maps to be implemented "that, on average, provide access times that are sublinear on the number of elements in the collection". Therefore, it could be represented internally as a hash table (with O(1) lookup), a search tree (with O(log(N)) lookup), or any other data structure, as long as the complexity is better than O(N).

#### With JavaScript object

```js
const urls = {
  "title 1": "https://example.com/1",
  "title 2": "https://example.com/2",
};
console.log(urls["title 1"]);
console.log(urls["Non-existing title"] ?? "No URL found for this title");
```

#### With a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

```js
const urlMap = new Map();
urlMap.set("title 1", "https://example.com/1");
urlMap.set("title 2", "https://example.com/2");

console.log(urlMap.get("title 1"));
console.log(urlMap.get("Non-existing title") ?? "No URL found for this title");
```

#### Lookup URL by titles following a specific pattern

If your titles follow a specific pattern and you want to be smart about things and not waste storage unnecessarily you could also do something like the following:

- parse title to obtain a lookup key and other information encoded in the title
- use title to lookup the base URL
- use other information encoded in the title to adjust the URL (path params, search params etc.)

Here a very simple example based on your example. Depending on the complexity of your title and your URLs this can get much more complex.

```js
const urls = {
  title: new URL("https://example.com"),
  anothertitle: new URL("https://anothertitle.net")
};

/**
 * Gets a URL with parameter for a title with a specific format.
 * @param {string} title title
 * @returns {URL} Url
 */
function getUrlForTitle(title) {
  const [key, pathValue] = title.split(" "); // you could of course use some Regex here and throw an error if it doesn't match
  const url = urls[key];
  if (url === undefined) throw new Error(`No URL found for title '${title}'`);
  url.pathname = `/${pathValue}`;
  return url;
}

console.log(getUrlForTitle("title 1").toString());
console.log(getUrlForTitle("title 2").toString());
console.log(getUrlForTitle("title 12").toString());
console.log(getUrlForTitle("anothertitle 145").toString());
// errors
console.log(getUrlForTitle("unknowntitle 145").toString());
```

```css
/* Stackoverflow: show only console */
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
  top: 0;
}
```

Comment: it seems that JS's map is equivalent to Python's dictionary. Is that correct? Also, if I have more than 2 attributes for each object, would these approaches be suitable?

Comment: Yes, you can think of it that way. Although I am not quite sure of the implementation details of Python's dictionary, but in terms of when or how (on a conceptual level) to use it, they are equivalent.

Comment: If I have more than 2 attributes for each object, would these approaches be suitable?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that. Depending on what you do having rules to create URLs might not be the best idea. I myself would probably.be careful with that since stuff like that can easily break when your titles don't follow those rules or they are very different so that you need a very complex system of rules. Do you have an example what you mean by "2 attributes"?

Comment: for example the object can be `{ title: "title 1", url: "https://example.com/1", author: "author 1"}`. It's possible that I also need to search for author, not title as well. Is that clearer?

Comment: Ah ok, got it. That's a problem, at least to do it efficiently. A lookup by author cannot be done by a a key since the key is based on the title. Therefore you would have to basically turn your JS Object or map into an array (using `map.entries()` or `Object.entries()`) and iterate through all the items using e.g. `filter()` or `find()` which is basically reverting to what you initially thought of when you have to query by author.
Alternatively, you could also create an additional map which maps authors to URLs (which reqires additional storage) or just use an array for everything.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256927/discussion-between-mushroomator-and-ooker).

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to filter the array based on the title and retrieve the corresponding URL, you can achieve it without creating instances of a class. You can use an object or a Map to store the titles as keys and their corresponding URLs as values. Here's how you can do it:

```js
const urls = [
    {
        title: "title 1",
        url: "https://example.com/1" 
    },
    {
        title: "title 2",
        url: "https://example.com/2" 
    },   
];

const urlsMap = new Map(urls.map(item => [item.title, item.url]));

const getUrlByTitle = (title) => {
    return urlsMap.get(title) || null; 
};

const titleToSearch = "title 1";
const url = getUrlByTitle(titleToSearch);
if (url) {
    console.log(`URL for ${titleToSearch}: ${url}`);
} else {
    console.log(`No URL found for ${titleToSearch}`);
}
```

In this approach:

- You define the URLs as key-value pairs in an object (`urls`).
- The `getUrlByTitle` function takes a title as input and returns the corresponding URL from the `urls` object.
- If the title is found in the `urls` object, it returns the corresponding URL; otherwise, it returns `null`.

This approach eliminates the need to create instances of a class and avoids memory overhead. It also simplifies the code and makes it more concise.

Comment: If I have more than 2 attributes for each object, would these approaches be suitable?